# How to get dates for specific weekday for N weeks from a given start date

Tags: c#, .net

I want to return an array of DateTime objects containing the next count number of `Wednesdays` on or after the given date using C#. Heres the method.

```
 public DateTime[] GetNextWednesdays(int count, string startDate)
 {
     throw new NotImplementedException();
 }
```

Having issues about how to go about doing this without an end date.

Comment: find the first Wednesday and then do `.AddDays(7)` for `count - 1` times to get the rest.

Comment: You can use `.DayOfWeek` to check the current day of the week on a `DateTime`.

Comment: Please always add a meaningful title to your question. Your title should indicate the content of your question more than the things you're working with. I've edited it for you.

Comment: Well, without an end date or a spec on the number results, you are *almost* out of luck. You could have your function be an integrator block that returns a `IEnumerable<DateTime>`, using `yield return` to let the caller decide how to end the calculation

Comment: @Flydog isn't that what `count` is for?

Comment: why accept a `string` if you need a `DateTime`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it in this way, live demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JR7Rv3)

**Updated**

After considering @John's recommend, you should check more condition like below

```
wednesday = wednesday > startDate ? startDate : wednesday.AddDays(7); 
// Wednesdays on or after the given date


public static DateTime[] GetNextWednesdays(int count, DateTime startDate)
{
        var wednesday = startDate.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Wednesday - startDate.DayOfWeek); // Get the date of Wednesday in week
        wednesday = wednesday > startDate ? startDate : wednesday.AddDays(7); // Wednesdays on or after the given date

        var result = new DateTime[count];
        result[0] = wednesday;

        for(int i = 1; i < count; i++)
        {
            wednesday = wednesday.AddDays(7);
            result[i] = wednesday;
        }


        return result;
}
```

**Output** *Let's say `startDate` is `1/16/2020 12:00:00 AM`*

```
1/22/2020 12:00:00 AM
1/29/2020 12:00:00 AM
2/5/2020 12:00:00 AM
2/12/2020 12:00:00 AM
2/19/2020 12:00:00 AM
2/26/2020 12:00:00 AM
3/4/2020 12:00:00 AM
3/11/2020 12:00:00 AM
3/18/2020 12:00:00 AM
3/25/2020 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Does that work for instances when `Today` is after Wednesday? I think in that case it will get the *previous* Wednesday.

Comment: can you please explain to me -(int)

Comment: I've just updated my answer to be more details. Please take a look

Comment: The [first date](https://rextester.com/DXTS41872) for 2020/01/10 is wrong.

Comment: Why does a start date of 2020/01/10 return 2020/01/08 as the first Wednesday? OP's problem statement is "on or after the given date".

Comment: I try to get the `Wednesday` in the week, So it's correct, sir. https://ibb.co/LZbbP32

Comment: @Anonymous That's not what OP is asking for though.

Comment: thanks guys i just didnt know how to go about this. i knew i needed a for loop but was completely stuck after that.

Comment: So does this answer your question? @DPier

Comment: OP you probably want to replace the `var wednesday = ` line with `startDate.AddDays(Math.Max(0, -(startDate.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Wednesday)));` to ensure you don't get a Wednesday in the past (relative to your start date).

Comment: *containing the next count number of wednesdays*, sir @John

Comment: Yeah, It's my pleasure @DPier

Comment: any advice on how i can become better at solving these types of problems with little help?

Comment: My answer is correct and the OP has been accepted it. I didn't know why someone is downvoting my answer too much, sir @John

Comment: Your answer isn't correct. As a native speaker of English, I can tell you that _"on or after the given date"_ means that it cannot occur before the given date. The sentence does not allow for that. _"an array containing the next count number of Wednesdays"_ also does not allow for previous Wednesdays. OP has probably accepted your answer because they haven't noticed the flaw.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you. So I've just updated my answer to make it correctly sir @John

Answer (score 5):

A slightly shorter version for your consideration:

```cs
public DateTime[] GetNextWednesdays(int count, string startDate)
{
    var start = DateTime.Parse(startDate);      
    var wednesday = start.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Wednesday-start.DayOfWeek);
    start = (wednesday > start) ? wednesday : wednesday.AddDays(7); 
    return Enumerable.Range(0,count).Select(i => start.AddDays(i*7).Date).ToArray();
}
```